# Inherit branch policies for newly created branches on Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, branch, pull-request

We have a git repository on Azure DevOps and already configured some branch policies for some branches (master, develop, etc..). Our current rules are as follows:

1. Require a minimum number of reviewers

   - Minimum number of reviewers: 2
   - Prohibit the most recent pusher from approving their own changes
   - When new changes are pushed:

     - Reset all approval votes (does not reset votes to reject or wait)
2. Check for comment resolution

   - Required
3. Automatically included reviewers

   - Required ones..
   - Optional ones..

Seems like this:
[image: Azure DevOps branch policies and settings]

Now what we would like to have is to have this config for the newly created branches in the future. Because whenever I create a new branch, it comes with no policies and I need to add every config manually.

I've checked official Microsoft documentation(s), blog posts, youtube videos and I also tried to look for the options that Azure DevOps provide, but couldn't find it anywhere.

Is that possible to have newly created branches come with default branch policy on Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that possible to have newly created branches come with default branch policy on Azure DevOps?

Yes. You can refer to following two methods to set the default branch policy for new branches.

Method1: Navigate to **Project Settings -> Repositories -> Policies**. You can set the branch name of the repo and add the related branch policy.

[image]

In this case, all repos in the Project will apply this rule.

Method2: Navigate to **Project Settings -> Repositories -> Select Repo -> Policies -> Select Branch Folder**.  We can create a branch policy at **Folder** level.

For example:

[image]

All Branches in the target repo under the Branch Folder will apply this rule.

To create the branch folder, we can navigate to **Azure Repo -> Branches** and create a new branch with the folder name.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Method 2 (policy at folder level) works perfect for my case.  We also have a folder called `Releases` and I created policy for that folder.  Now each branch under that folder has the policy, thanks.